# how can manipulate the different kind of array (string, int, char) as same format such as string in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, arraylist

I have a collection of objects that each object would contains a different kind of array (string[],int[],char[]) or even single value as different types.

I want to get the values of each array as single format such as string  and convert it to a comma text value.

here is the code that manipulates an object of collection as "UInt16[]"

```
UInt16[] arrCapabilities = (UInt16[])(queryObj["Capabilities"]);
foreach (UInt16 arrValue in arrCapabilities)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Capabilities: {0}", arrValue);
}
```

Comment: Could you please ellaborate your question?

Comment: the problem is this that how I can get the different kind of array value with unique manipulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the following code:

```
IEnumerable array = queryObj["Capabilities"] as IEnumerable;
if(array != null)
{
    foreach(var item in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(queryObj["Capabilities"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to convert your array of whatever into an IEnumerable of string:

```
var myStrings = from c in arrCapabilities select c.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

To Expand on Daniels answer and get the csv string you are after:

```
IEnumerable array = queryObj["Capabilities"] as IEnumerable;
if(array != null)
{
     var csvString = String.Join(", ", array.Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()));
     Console.WriteLine(csvString);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(queryObj["Capabilities"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
void WriteToConsole<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
        Console.WriteLine("Capabilities: " + item);
}
```